# reverse ssh tunnel, why it gets ipv6 address?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, sshd

I have two machines

1. ssh Machine1-IPv4
2. ssh -R 15:localhost:15 Machine2-IPv4

On the Machine2-IPv4, I can run

telnet ::1 15

netstat -ptln | grep 15 shows

tcp6 ... ::1:53 ...

However, I need an IPv4. What causes the IP to be IPv6?

Comment: You need to request an IPv4 address from your provider (either your ISP or VPS provider depending on what you are using).

Comment: However I ssh to both machines with IPv4.
The problem is I get ::1 to reach server when I use reverse tunnel.
ssh 10.20.30.40 (works)
ssh 30.40.50.60 (works)

From 10.20.30.40:
ssh -R 15:localhost:15 30.40.50.60 (works)
On 30.40.50.60:
netstat -ptln | grep 15 shows ::1

Comment: If you only need IPv4 loopback, specify that: `-R127.0.0.1:15:localhost:15`. If you want both loopbacks, you must either specify two `-R` options, or specify one with `*` which if sshd on machine2 is configured to permit it actually listens on _all_ addresses (on all interfaces) both IPv4 and IPv6; this may or may not be a security vulnerability in your environment. This is not programming or development.